# Calling Spring Cacheable method within Cacheable method class cast exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-cache

I am trying to use Spring Cacheable but am getting a class cast exception

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = CacheableTest.class, loader = AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)
@Configuration
@EnableCaching
public class CacheableTest {
    public static final String CACHE = "cache";

    @Bean
    public CacheManager cacheManager() {
        return new ConcurrentMapCacheManager(CACHE);
    }

    @Autowired
    DataService service;

    @Test
    public void cacheTest() {
        final String name = "name";
        Data a = service.getData(name);
        Data b = service.getData(new String(name));
        Assert.assertSame(a, b);
        String c = service.getValue(service.getData(name));
        String d = service.getValue(service.getData(new String(name)));
        Assert.assertSame(c, d);
        String e = service.getValue(name);
        String f = service.getValue(new String(name));
        Assert.assertSame(e, f);
    }

    public static class Data {
        private String value;
        public Data(String value) {
            this.value = value;
        }
    }

    @Service
    public static class DataService {
        @Resource
        private DataService self;

        @Cacheable(CACHE)
        public Data getData(String name) {
            return new Data(name);
        }

        @Cacheable(CACHE)
        public String getValue(Data data) {
            return data.value;
        }

        @Cacheable(CACHE)
        public String getValue(String name) {
            return self.getData(name).value;
        }
    }

}
```

The exception said `CacheableTest$Data cannot be cast to java.lang.String` which happens at line String e. Do we know why?

Answer (score 3):

You have declared 2 methods with same parameters but different returned type.:

```java
public Data getData(String name)
public String getValue(String name)
```

And you marked both of them as `@Cacheable` with same cache name `CACHE`. As a result you are sharing single cache to store results from both methods. Both methods have exactly same parameters (`String`) so cache keys calculated by spring for both `Data` and `Value` will collide.

The first method that is called will return result which spring will put in  the cache, and the second one will try to retrieve this same result from cache (because the cache name and method parameter match) and try to cast it to other type - hence, class cast exception.

It's pretty much the same as if you did this:

```
Map<String, Object> cache = new HashMap<>();
cache.put("key", "value1");
int i = (Integer)cache.get("key")
```

Comment: Ah ok. So `@Cacheable` only checks for the input parameters by default to locate the cached result. Thanks for answering the "why". Do you know how to resolve this (e.g. make `@Cacheable` to combine the return type+method name+input parameters as unique key to locate the cache)?

Comment: The solution I think is just use separate caches for different types. E.g. you could call one cache `"dataCache"` the other one `"valueCache"`. I can't think of any good reason to keep both types of objects in single cache. At least this is the way I fixed it and it worked for me.

You could also make a custom key generator but haven't done that.

Comment: To be honest, my answer above is really just a best guess at what is happening. I've run into the same issue, hence found this question. I couldn't find any detailed spring documentation on how `@Cacheable` works regarding this particular subject. If any one could point me to it, I'm happy to link to it in my answer and revise it if needed.